# Oracle SQL Case with Condition

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle8i

I have a question regarding Oracle SQL case statement.

in the where condition I would like to apply the following condition.
if salary_date is null then effective_date should be greater than 01-Jan-2016

I have the tried as

```
case when salary_date is null then
trunc(effective_date) >= '01-JAN-2016' else
         null end
```

However the above resulted in

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Unrelated, but: do ***NOT*** rely on the evil implicit data type conversion. `'01-JAN-2016'`  is a string value, *not* a `DATE`. Use a proper date literal, e.g. `DATE '2016-01-01'` or `to_date('2016-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that SQL interpreter expects to see the value after 'then' keyword, whereas you have a condition clause.

Try something like this maybe:

```
case when salary_date is null and trunc(effective_date) >= '01-JAN-2016' 
     then <value you need> 
     else null
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I should be checking only when salary_date is null , then effective_date must be greater than '01-JAN-2016'

Comment: @user75ponic: this is exactly what that condition is doing.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - not really. If you read the OP's question in its entirety, not just the code snippet, you will see he was trying to use a case "condition" in a WHERE clause. Alas, Oracle SQL only has case expressions, so "case" was the wrong tool to begin with. Something like that would work in PL/SQL, but not in plain SQL.  massive_dynamic shows an example of (correct) use of case expressions, but this is not related to the OP's problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this without CASE statement

```
SELECT
..
..
WHERE ( trunc(effective_date) >= '01-JAN-2016' AND salary_date is null ) 
OR ( <some other condition> )
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I should be checking only when salary_date is null , then effective_date must be greater than '01-JAN-2016'

Comment: this is what the AND condition is doing inside round brackets .. try the code and check for result

Comment: only when salarydate is null the `trunc(effective_date) >= '01-JAN-2016'` condition will be checked because of AND

Comment: @mhasan - The OP is right. The logic is very simple: IF salary_date is null THEN eff_date > whatever. IF a THEN b can be written as "NON a OR b". You wrote it as "**a AND b**". You got TWO things wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
...where salary_date is not null or effective_date >= date '2016-01-01'
```

Since Oracle SQL does not have "IF... THEN", use basic logic to transform your boolean expression. IF a THEN b is the same thing as (NON a) OR b. This is what I did above.

DO...NOT... compare dates to strings. `'01-JAN-2016'` is a string, not a date. You MUST convert it to a date, for example with `to_date('01-JAN-2016', 'dd-MON-yyyy')`.

Or, as an alternative, note how I input a "date literal" (a fixed date). If I don't need to input a time of day, I can use the expression `date '2016-01-01'`, which is a SQL Standard (ANSI) "date literal". Then you don't need to give a date format model; it MUST ALWAYS be in the exact format yyyy-mm-dd.

Comment: Whoever downvoted, can you please leave a note explaining your objection to my answer? Thank you!